# Loading javascript resources in custom controls on xPages partial refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, custom-controls, xpages

I have several custom controls in my xPage, each of the custom control contain client side javascript resources.

I have noticed that if I add custom controls to my xpages and set rendered to false (or true) the javascript resorces are loaded in when i load my xpage instead of when the custom control is changed to true. I guess this is ok behaviour as if I set rendered to false the loaded property is still true. (I have not tested this by setting the loading property to false/true)

If I instead use the dynamic Content control in extLib the custom controls or the javascript resources are not loaded when the xpage is loaded and if I trigger the load of a custom control from my xpage the custom control is loaded in nicely but the javascript resources are not loaded in.

My guess here is that both these scenarious is related. all javascript resources are only loaded in to the xpage if they are loaded when the xpage is loaded. (i.e I can't find a way to load in javascript resources using partial refresh)

So...regardless if I am using extlib or not, Is there a way to load javascript resources located in a custom control after the xpages has been loaded using partial refresh. I have tried different ways using the onClientLoad event but not managed to get it working.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Why can't you just load the js all the time? Then the functions could be called after a partial refresh. Are you just concerned with the size of the download?

Comment: Thank you all for responding to this question. I found a few javascript on the internet that did what I wanted, apparently this is also a problem for non xPages application doing ajax calls. However, I'm going with another solution in my project so this is not important any more

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could load the JS dynamically by inserting a JS tag in the DOM. For example dojo.io.script.get does this internally.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/io/script.html

You could trigger this in the onComplete callback of the XSP partial refresh call.

Comment: Any ideas how to get hold of the onComplete callback from this call: XSP.showContent("#{id:dynC}","cc1");

Comment: if you use the example from Tims post for the partial refresh you can get he call back 

 XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div1}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div2}", {
            onComplete: function() {
                XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div3}", {
                    onComplete: function() {
                        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:div4}");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});